# Spring Cloud Config Server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-config

I am using the Spring Cloud Config Server and able to detect the changes from the git repository and pass it to the Config clients.

There are two ways, I have implemented it:

1. After making changes (commit and push) in the git repository, I make a curl request  curl -X POST http://server:port/bus/refresh and it works fine. For this I am using RabbitMQ as the Spring Cloud Bus.

Reference: 
http://tech.asimio.net/2017/02/02/Refreshable-Configuration-using-Spring-Cloud-Config-Server-Spring-Cloud-Bus-RabbitMQ-and-Git.html

2. After making changes (commit and push) in the git repository, I make a curl request  curl -X POST http://server:port/refresh (with no /bus in the url) and it works fine. I am NOT using Spring Cloud Bus here.

Reference: https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/

So both works fine, so Is there any advantage of using Spring Cloud Bus, or in Production environment, will there be any issue with going without Spring Cloud Bus? As there will be extra effort needed to get setup the RabbitMQ Cluster (HA) as Spring Cloud Bus in production.

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`/refresh` will only refresh the config client to whom the request was made. It only refreshes locally. Using `/bus/refresh` will refresh all clients connected to the bus. In other words it will refresh all bus clients (or a subset if the `destination` parameter is set).

Comment: Hello Spencer do you happen to have a sample application? I am trying to understand spring cloud config, with spring cloud bus. reading properties file from a git hub repo and update as it changes.

Comment: @Jesse this doc https://spencer.gibb.us/blog/2015/09/24/spring-cloud-config-push-notifications/ might help you and this was written by spencer itself this has all the info you might need